# possible to connect heidisql to mysql cpanel

Tags: cpanel, heidisql

Is it possible to connect [heidisql](http://www.heidisql.com/) to my cpanel mysql ?. I don't know how to connect the heidisql to cpanel mysql.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can connect your mysql database through  heidisql, Login your cpanel and allow your IPS IP to remote mysql access host list and try now. If you still getting any issues them ask your server admin to enable to port 3306 in server firewall so that you access your mysql server from remote IP

Comment: I tried that but still not working even at my home I tried to connect

Comment: Have you added port 3306 in server firewall allow list ?